# Looking for html/flash/ajax uploader component with specific requirements

Tags: javascript, html, flash, file-upload

There is a number of Flash and AJAX based uploaders around. I need a file upload component for an existing form in an existinc application, so I have very specific requirements for it. Maybe somebody knows one off the top of their head and saves me a lot of research.

I need a file upload component that has a progress bar and "upload" button next to it (= standalone functionality, no connection to the submit event of a surrounding form).

It should be either Flash or Prototype based. No JQuery or Moo, as the app runs with prototype.

If server-side scripting is needed, it must be PHP. No Perl, no ASP.

On successful upload, I need a custom Javascript function triggered. (I need to update a file list that is displayed on the same page.)

Good looks would be a plus.

The possibility of filtering file names before upload (no Umlauts, spaces..) would be a plus.

I will try to give this question a bounty in a minute if I'm allowed to.

Edit: I can't seem to open a bounty. Do I have to wait first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) does seem to fulfill all my requirements: Free, open source, highly configurable, good examples. Will go with that and post about it later.

Edit: Yes it does. It is a bit tricky and the documentation is, albeit complete, not too accessible, but SWFUpload is very configurable and provides everything I need. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you would not switch now since it has been quite a while, but [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) was built off of SWFUpload I believe and has added several features to it. Not quite sure exactly what they added but I know that Uploadify allows the user to upload multiple files at once using ctrl + clicking on all desired files. These files are then queued up for uploading. This is all displayed to the user in a queue format with loading bars for each file. When the file is finished downloading it is removed from the queue. Uploadify worked perfectly for all of my needs.